# How do I make my computer name visible on the local network and Windows?

Tags: networking, samba, xrdp

Sorry if I am asking this in the wrong place, but I am no *nix expert and I failed to find an answer to my question, although I found similar issues on XRDP and Samba tags.

When I use RDP on Windows computers on local network, I am able to do so without typing the IP address. I just write the computer name (e.g. John-Computer) and I am able to connect through Remote Desktop Connection. Now, I have setup an Ubuntu desktop with xrpd, but I am only able to connect to it using its IP address.

Is it possible to make my Computer Name visible to Windows computers to simplify connections and access to web services hosted on the Ubuntu machine? If not, what would you suggest for me?

Thanks in advance.